# TYPO3 fluid menu condition for current page

Tags: menu, typo3, conditional-statements, fluid

I'm using TYPO3 v. 8.7 and ext. vhs

Is it possible to make a condition that checks for current page? Have tried the code below but it does not work. I think it should then be possible to check for Current page

```
<v:page.menu expandAll="1" entryLevel="1" >
  <f:for each="{menu}" as="menuPage" iteration="iteration">
    <f:if condition="{menuPage.isCurrentPage}">
      <f:then>is current page</f:then>
      <f:else>is not current page</f:else>
    </f:if>
  </f:for>
</v:page.menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of EXT:VHS you are using, maybe an old one (as you wrote the deprecated  `v:page.menu` instead of `v:menu` ).

You can discover all the options available for each item on the menu and their current value just using

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

Like this:

```
<v:page.menu expandAll="1" entryLevel="1" >
   <f:for each="{menu}" as="menuPage" iteration="iteration">
   <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
   <f:if condition="{menuPage.uid} == {data.uid}">
       <f:then>is current page </f:then>
       <f:else>is not current page</f:else>
      </f:if>
   </f:for>
</v:page.menu>
```

On version 6.0.0 (the one I am currently using) there are the boolean `current` and `active` so your code should be just:

```
<v:menu expandAll="1" entryLevel="1" >
   <f:for each="{menu}" as="menuPage" iteration="iteration">
   <f:if condition = "{menuPage.current}">
       <f:then>is current page </f:then>
       <f:else>is not current page</f:else>
      </f:if>
   </f:for>
</v:menu>
```

Plus, if you just need a different class for your "active" or "current" items, you can also use the `v:menu` arguments ´classActive´ and `classCurrent`

for example:

```
<v:menu expandAll="1" entryLevel="1" classCurrent="is-current" classActive="is-active">
   <f:for each="{menu}" as="menuPage" iteration="iteration">
     <li class="{menuPage.class}">
        <f:link.page pageUid="{menuPage.uid}" title="{menuPage.linktext}">{menuPage.linktext}</f:link.page>
     </li>
   </f:for>
</v:menu>
```

Comment: I'm using v. 6.0. I'll try your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily resolved it as follows. But I don't think that's the nicest solution.

```
<v:page.menu expandAll="1" entryLevel="1" >
  <f:for each="{menu}" as="menuPage" iteration="iteration">
    <f:if condition="{menuPage.uid} == {data.uid}">
      <f:then>is current page </f:then>
      <f:else>is not current page</f:else>
    </f:if>
  </f:for>
</v:page.menu>
```